# Incentives for or against private static final immutables on @service in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm fairly new to programming in the area of professional software development, and my collegues had a discussion about using fields like the following in a Spring @Service annotated class:

```
private static final Map<Key, Value> someMap;
static {
    Map<Key, Value> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(aKey, aValue);
    someMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

Can I leave out any keywords without compromising some safety/features under the following premises:

- The map is to never be modified in any way except directly by a programmer with access to the source code
- The map is not made available to any classes outside
- The class containing the map is annotated as a Service with default scope for SpringBoot
- **EDIT** Assume both Key and Value are Enum values without any other information or functionality in them.
- **EDIT** The Map is intended as a better-maintainable alternative to a method containing a switch case statement
- **EDIT** The map is in no way made accesible to any other class

What are the advantages or disadvantages of this approach over using something like this:

```
private final Map<Key, Value> someMap;

public MyClass() {
    Map<Key, Value> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(aKey, aValue);
    someMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

Comment: What is that aValue? Is it something that contains state? If it does, it could make a difference.

Comment: Pretty much anything called `Value` is going to be a type that has state. The question is whether it's mutable state. The value type being mutable isn't too much of a problem, but if the key type is mutable, now that could get interesting.

Comment: Ok. Mutable state. And for the Value.

Comment: It's a Spring @Service. It's a singleton. When run as a part of tests, Spring re-uses beans across tests, and the same object will be used for all tests. However, if you mark a tests as DirtiesContext, it will create a new context, and it will be a different object in that context, although of the same class. In the case of the field being "static", the two beans will share the same map even if the test is marked as DirtiesContext.

Comment: @Pradyumna Hope this clears it up a bit

Answer (score 3):

The main question that you should ask yourself is how many instances of the class you are going to created.

**One class instance**

The default scope of @Service is singleton then there isn't much difference whether you create the map as a static member or a regular one. There will be only one instance of the map and the only difference will be in the moment when its initialization happens. With the singleton scope there is no real reason to use static members.

However, by creating the map as a regular member of the class you may avoid some problem with static members in the future. For instance, if you ever would like to unit test your class and stub the map for some testing scenario, it will be much more problematic with a static member. Static members can't benefit from the dependency injection and @Value injection in case you need it.

**Many class instances**

If you change the default scope of you @Service class and you would like to share some private internal state by all instances then using a static member might be a reasonable choice in some cases. You must remember that the map can be accessed or modified by instances concurrently, hence you should make sure you design your class with thread safety in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The two approaches differ in the scope of the member `someMap`; one is `static` and the other an instance member. This is a matter of logic - either the member should belong to the class, or it should belong to the instance. You haven't given us enough information to know in your particular case, but if multiple instances of the class need access to the same map in the class, it's obviously going to have to be `static`. The disadvantage of the instance approach in this case is that the program will break. OTOH, if each instance needs its own map, then it'll be the `static` version that breaks the program.

So you tell us - does the map belong with the class, or with each instance of the class?

Also, the map is not immutable unless its elements also are. You can't change what's in the map, but if the keys, for example, are mutable you can potentially get some very peculiar outcomes.

Comment: Yes, but would it make a difference? A Spring Service is a singleton.

Comment: That it's a singleton is irrelevant. Does it make the map or anything in it available to anything, including itself, or does it just load the map and forget it? Are there any references to any key or value from anywhere other than the map, or is the map an oubliette? If the map or any of its entries are used at all, it makes a difference.

Comment: The map is only used internally and not accessible from outside via methods, and neither keys nor values have states, they are primitive enums.